# loading text in to textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the value of textarea when the button is clicked, I tried loading the page using `.load()` but I am getting `[object object]` in the textarea instead of the data from the php page. What am doing wrong here? What I actually want to do here is that I have cancel and save button and there is text loaded to textarea already via php when the page loads so if the user clicks cancel I want to restore the original text in the textarea.

```
 <textarea class="trd" id="txt"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancel">Cancel</button>

$('#cancel').click(function() {
            var res = $('#txt').load('somedata.php');
            $("#txt").val(res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fetch the contents of the remote resource and then using the success callback assign the result to the textarea

```
$('#cancel').click(function () {
    $.get('somedata.php', function (res) {
        $("#txt").val(res);
    })
});
```

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will return a promise object, not the contents of the remote resource